# What sort of algorithms can RNN not learn?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

People are developing things like a neural Turing machine which can learn simple algorithms.

What is the limit of what an RNN can learn?

For example for a RNN text generator, can it learn to copy a general character? Or does it have to learn to copy each character separately?

What are some things that an RNN can't possibly do that a neural Turing machine can do.

Comment: RNNs are turing complete, although impractically so.

Comment: just like a human brain! Maybe it just needs a very very very large internal state.